# Hash::check Succeeds, but Auth::attempt fails

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-sanctum

so I'm new to Laravel. Just learning with a test project.

I'm using Vue to make an SPA with a Laravel 8 and Sanctum backend.

I successfully create a registration system, but am unable to login.

Below is my code.

**register function**

```
    {
        // Validate the user input
        $request->validate([
            "company" => ["required"],
            "firstName" => ["required"],
            "lastName" => ["required"],
            "phone" => ["required"],
            "email" => ["required", "email", "unique:users"],
            "password" => ["required", "min:8", "confirmed"],
        ]);
        // Unique Company Identifier
        $uniqueCode = unique_company_code();

        // Create A DB Name
        $dbName = "tn_";
        $dbName .= substr(str_replace(".", "", str_replace(" ", "", $request->company)), 0, 4);
        $dbName .= substr($uniqueCode, 0, 6);
        try
        {
            DB::beginTransaction();
            $company = Company::create([
                "Name" => $request->company,
                "Code" => $uniqueCode,
                "DatabaseName" => $dbName,
                "Status" => "Waiting Activation",
                "AllowedUsers" => 3,
                "RegisteredUsers" => 1
            ]);
            User::create([
                "CompanyID" => $company->id,
                "FirstName" => $request->firstName,
                "LastName" => $request->lastName,
                "Phone" => $request->phone,
                "Email" => $request->email,
                "Password" => Hash::make($request->input("password")),
                "AccountType" => "Admin"
            ]);
            // Create New DB
            $query = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $dbName CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';";
            DB::statement($query);
            DB::commit();

            return response()->json(["action" => "Success", "msg" => "<p>Congratulations, Your Account has been created!!<br><b>You will get a confirmation email once your Account has been Approved and Activated</b></p>"], 200);
        }
        catch (\Exception $e)
        {
            DB::rollback();
            return response()->json(array("Error" => "<p>Oop...Seems like there was an error at our end.<br /> Please contact us at <b>support@simpleflow.in</b> for assistance</p>"), 500);
            logger($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Login Function

```
    {
        $request->validate([
            "email" => "required",
            "password" => "required"
        ]);

        $user = User::where("Email", $request->email)->first();
        $check = Hash::check($request->password, $user->Password);
        //return $check;

        if (Auth::attempt(["Email" => $request->email, "password" => $request->password]))
        {
            return response()->json(Auth::user(), 200);
        }

        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            "Login" => "The Provided Credentials are Incorrect.",
            "emailId" => $request->email,
            "password" => $request->password
        ]);
    }
```

**Note: I've tried with both "Password" and "password" in the Auth::attempt() function, it doesn't work**

**Note 2 : The comment 'return $check' returns '1' in the browser console. Which means that the hashed password (which is loaded in the user model), matches the password in the request...right?**

Lastly, my users table
[image: Database]

I've been trying to fix this since last night and have gone through multiple google searches and also tried a few things, but nothing works.

I also cannot find a way to debug the Auth::attempt method directly, like I don't know what's failing.

Please help... I've been pulling my hair out due to this.

Update : So I was just screwing around... and I changed my column names in my table from (Email, Password) to (email, password)... and in my code, reverted to
`$request->only('email', 'password')`

For some reason...it works.... I still don't know why I was having this error and how I could possibly make it work if my table column names are capitalized (I like it that way... :/ )

So while my issue is solved ATM... any explanation into this would be really appreciated...

Comment: Update : My User model 'extends Authenticatable'